ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' , geopy in flask
I'm importing pandas and geopy in flask , but its seems there output says no module name pandas and geopy , but already installed pandas and geopy
from flask import Flask, render_template , request ,send_file
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

